# Android AudioManager setMode() permission Denial

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I try to setMode(mode_in_call) to change audio mode when I play a media.
So,i'm sure i add the permission

and i write in code like this:
AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
mAudioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);

here is the problem:
i use Sumsung i9000 i9023 
it doesn't work,and the log Phone Related Audio Settings Permission Denial: setMode()
but i try Sony x10 LT15i,it can modify the mode correctly.
why doesn't this happen.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see what permission you say you added but make sure it's:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

Comment: thx，I have fix it by SetMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION)

Comment: MODE_IN_CALL is restricted for third party applications from Android Lollipop. You can make use of this only if your application is a system application. Best method as a third party application would be to use MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION with proper audio routing control.

Answer (score 0):

Note that MODE_IN_CALL can only be selected by the main telephony application with permission Manifest.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE.

"Manifest.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" - Allows modification of the telephony state - power on, mmi, etc. Does not include placing calls. Not for use by third-party applications.

Reference link:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager#setCommunicationDevice(android.media.AudioDeviceInfo)

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#MODIFY_PHONE_STATE